# Throwing a baseball against the back of a car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

We, some fellow students and I, are trying to figure out what to. But we simply do not know which formula to use at question a.

We found the following:
$\Delta P=(2mv_{ball,i}M)/(m+M)$

Could someone please give feedback, if we are on the right track?

For some unknown reason, you decide to throw baseballs of mass m against the back of a car of mass $M$ (much larger than m), which is free to move frictionlessly on the ground. Say you throw the balls with speed u and they leave your hand at a mass rate of $\sigma$(i.e.,$\sigma= m \Delta t$, where Δt is the time interval between two throws). The balls bounce elastically off the back window of the car.

(a) Find the change in the momentum of the car for the first ball that hits it. Also find the associated rate of change by dividing by the time interval Δt. (b) After some time, the car has reached speed $v(t)$. Again, find the rate of change of momentum of the car as a ball hits it. (c) Use Newton’s second law to write down a differential equation for $v(t)$. (d) Solve your differential equation for $v(t)$, assuming the car starts from rest. (e) Integrate your expression for $v(t)$ to find the position of the car as a function of time, starting from $x(0) = x_0$ . (f, BONUS) Find $v(t)$ and $x(t)$ in the case the back window of the car is open, so the balls accumulate inside it.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149514/45164